# Tables in rmarkdown?

Tags: r, shiny, markdown, xtable

I have my results as a table from R code. When I View(results) in R, I would get a pretty table like :
[image]
Then I transfer my code to shiny app, with download option. I could not find a proper command in Rmarkdown to drown my table properly. I have tried every single packages, like xtable :

````
---
title: "All pages landscape"
output: pdf_document
classoption: landscape
---



```{r results = "asis", echo=FALSE}

x.side <- xtable:: xtable(ali1(), caption = "A sideways table",align=c("rp{2cm}p{0.7cm}p{0.7cm}p{1cm}p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm}"))
print(x.side, floating = TRUE,type="latex")
```
````

Without using `align` its look like :

[image]

and with `align` (I have tried to show all columns ) :

[image]

Beside that when I tried to use the `rotate.colnames=TRUE` I have got the error :

> Error : pandoc document conversion failed with error 43

My aim is to have the table in a single piece! I was not able to find a command that fix the column's width and break the rows to have multi lines!

Any Idea is highly appreciated!

Comment: PDF documents are formatted with LaTeX, you might have more luck asking on tex.stackexchange, for example this question: [write column header on multiple line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79544/write-column-header-on-multiple-line).

Comment: I use the Latex `parbox` function in the column names in order to control the width of the columns. Something like `names(mydfTable) <- c("\\parbox[c][2.5em][c]{0.6in}{\\centering col title 1 line 1\\\\col title 1 line2}", "\\parbox[c][2.5em][c]{0.6in}{\\centering col title 2 line 1\\\\col title line2}")` and so on. This will force the contents in these to wrap if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new possibility of taking a screenshot of html widgets for further implementation, in for example pdf document (You need to download for that package: `webshot`). The screenshot of the datatable (`DT` package) is taken and used as an image in `rmarkdown`. You should try it out, the table is nicely formatted.

Here is a sample code:

````
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
---

```{r, fig.align='center', fig.pos='htb!', echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, tidy=TRUE}
library(DT)
library(webshot)
datatable(mtcars[1:15,],rownames=FALSE, options = list(dom='t',ordering=F))
```
````

**UPDATE**

I have tried full code which You have gave me on base of [this shiny app example](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/download-knitr-reports.html)

Shiny App:

```
library(shiny)
library(rmarkdown)
library(knitr)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    title = 'Download a PDF report',
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        helpText(),
        selectInput('x', 'Build a regression model of mpg against:',
                    choices = names(mtcars)[-1]),
        radioButtons('format', 'Document format', c('PDF', 'HTML', 'Word'),
                     inline = TRUE),
        downloadButton('downloadReport')
      ),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput('regPlot')
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    data <- reactive({mtcars[ ,input$x, drop=FALSE]})

    regFormula <- reactive({
      as.formula(paste('mpg ~', input$x))
    })

    output$regPlot <- renderPlot({
      par(mar = c(4, 4, .1, .1))
      plot(regFormula(), data = mtcars, pch = 19)
    })

    output$downloadReport <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste('my-report', sep = '.', switch(
          input$format, PDF = 'pdf', HTML = 'html', Word = 'docx'
        ))
      },

      content = function(file) {
        src <- normalizePath('report_file.Rmd')

        # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
        # permission to the current working directory
        owd <- setwd(tempdir())
        on.exit(setwd(owd))
        file.copy(src, 'report_file.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)

        library(rmarkdown)
        out <- render('report_file.Rmd', switch(
          input$format,
          PDF = pdf_document(), HTML = html_document(), Word = word_document()
        ))
        file.rename(out, file)
      }
    )

  }
)
```

report_file.Rmd:

````
Here is my regression model:

```{r model, collapse=TRUE}
options(digits = 4)
fit <- lm(regFormula(), data = mtcars)
b   <- coef(fit)
summary(fit)
```

```{r, fig.align='center', fig.pos='htb!', echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, tidy=TRUE}
library(DT)
library(webshot)
datatable(data(),rownames=FALSE, options = list(dom='t',ordering=F))
```

The fitting result is $mpg = `r b[1]` + `r b[2]``r input$x`$.
Below is a scatter plot with the regression line.

```{r plot, fig.height=5}
par(mar = c(4, 4, 1, 1))
plot(regFormula(), data = mtcars, pch = 19, col = 'gray')
abline(fit, col = 'red', lwd = 2)
```
````

And it is working perfectly giving me desired pdf output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I exactly copied your code and I got the following error :  Error : Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting latex output.
Please change the output type of this document to HTML. Alternatively, you can allow
HTML output in non-HTML formats by adding this option to the YAML front-matter of
your rmarkdown file:

  always_allow_html: yes

Note however that the HTML output will not be visible in non-HTML formats.

Comment: I have tried the code that i posted and it works well, check out the screenshot i have added...Did You save this document as `.Rmd` and knitted it? Did You download the `webshot` and `DT` packages?If yes what versions of them do You have?

Comment: I have saved it as .Rmd and yes I installed both packages : webshot_0.4.1   and DT_0.2

Comment: what version of `DT` and `webshot` do You have?

Comment: When knitr detects an HTML widget object in a code chunk, it either renders the widget normally when the current output format is HTML, or **saves the widget as an HTML page and calls webshot to capture the screen of the HTML page when the output format is not HTML**: source: https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html-widgets.html

Comment: After I install webshot::install_phantomjs() , your code is working ! how I could use it for my function. I mean, I have calculated a table in shiny app, and its results is in a function called A() (in reactive function in shiny), In my app I have used a downloadHandler to send the table to markdown. But when I use your template and replace mtcars[1:15,] with my table I'm getting that error I explained before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150594/discussion-between-ali-hadjihoseini-and-malvina-a).

Comment: Check my update, thats all what i can do based on what You said, the code i have provided works perfectly and gives desired output with reactive data in form of screenshot from DT.

Comment: thank you very much !! updated version is working very well. I would appreciate if you could help me here :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45485907/call-choices-from-input-panel-in-other-functions/45486272#45486272

Comment: Just could you please tell me how should I increase the size ? datatable does not react to width and length !