# Call choices from input panel in other functions?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have a simple shiny app:

Read the zip file. Select some desired file and adjust the input panel based on the number of read files:

[image]

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("File", "Input checkbox"),
  selectInput("inSelect", "Select input",c())
  leafletOutput("mymap")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  cor<- reactive({
    x=input$File

    if (is.null(x))
      return(NULL)

    report_list <- c("Park result.txt",
                     "Park result minus",
                     "Park result plus")
    temp_files <- unzip(x$datapath)
    temp_files <- temp_files[grepl(paste(report_list, collapse = "|"), temp_files)]

    T=length(temp_files)

    A_new=c();for(i in 1:(T/3)){A_new[[i]]=c()}
    for(i in 1:(T/3)){A_new[[i]]=....}

    result <- list(T=T,A_new=A_new);
    return(result);
  })

observeEvent(cor(),{
updateSelectInput(session, "Select1",
                  label = paste(((cor()$T)/3),"different layout"),
                  choices = paste0("Layout",c(1:((cor()$T)/3))))
})

output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    infile=input$File
    if (is.null(infile))
      return(NULL)
    a2=cor()
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles("OpenTopoMap", group = "MapQuestOpen.Aerial") %>%
      addMarkers(data =a2$A_new[[1]],~long, ~lat, popup = ~as.character(mag), label = ~as.character(Name))%>% 

      addMeasure()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

At the end, in my `output$mymap` function, how could I set the parameter `A_new`, in a way that If user choose `layout1`, then plot show the map related to `A_new[[1]]` , if `layout2` then map should be `A_new[[2]]` to display ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the `observeEvent` which is a lot less code

```
 observeEvent(cor(),{
    updateSelectInput(session, "inSelect",label = paste(cor()$t1,"different layout"),choices = paste0("Layout",c(1:cor()$t1)))
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Anything defined within your reactive is not accessible from outside the reactive. So within the reactive, you do

```
x=input$File
```

so x is defined within your reactive, but not outside of your reactive! So in your observer:

```
observe({ 
if (is.null(x))
  return(NULL)
...
```

will not work, since x does not exist. I am guessing what you want to do is:

```
observe({ 
if (is.null(cor()))
  return(NULL)
...
```

which checks if the reactive is NULL. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank for the point ! I don't get the error any more, but still it doesn't react to changes ! I mean my select input does not update after running the code with reactive function

Comment: I have found the problem, was related to sidebar layout that I was using, I mixed up the orders now it's working again, but I have another question, would be great if you go through my updated question again. thank you very much.